# Function returning undefined in Geocoder

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using Google maps v3 geocoder to geocode an address then pass the 2 coordinate points from the jQuery file to a PHP file using `getJSON`.

**Problem:** However, I notice that the function that does the geocoding function keeps returning an undefined value! Thus the PHP file receives a undefined variable. Where did I go wrong?

**jQuery Code**

```
var search_latlng = geocodeAddress(search_location);
console.log(search_latlng);

$.getJSON('/main/get_places', {search_location: search_latlng}, function(json){
        $("#result_listing").html('');
 .
 .
 .
```

**Geocoder JS function**

```
function geocodeAddress(address) {

    var latlng = new Array(2);

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            latlng[0] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            latlng[1] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            return latlng;
        } else {
            console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return a value from that function via the callback to the Google code.  It makes no sense; the "geocode()" function is **asynchronous**.  The outer function will have returned by the time that your callback runs.

The proper way to do this is to mimic the Google API itself: give your function a callback parameter, and perform your "afterwards" work from there:

```
function geocodeAddress(address, callback) {

    var latlng = new Array(2);

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            latlng[0] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            latlng[1] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            callback(latlng); // call the callback function here
        } else {
            console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

*edit* — as an example of how you'd use this:

```
geocodeAddress(search_location, function(search_latlng) {
  console.log(search_latlng);
  $.getJSON('/main/get_places', {search_location: search_latlng}, function(json){
    $("#result_listing").html('');
    // ...
  });
});
```

It's like your original code, but instead of having the geocode result *returned* to your code, it's passed as the parameter to the callback function you provide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So `callback` is an ordinary function defined elsewhere that I pass into `geocoderAddress()`? Can the `callback()` function take the `latlng` variable and `return` it to another variable `search_latlng` to pass to the `getJSON` function?

Comment: What you're doing, essentially, is exactly the same thing that the Google API does to handle the core asynchronous transaction (the underlying HTTP request that satisfies the geocoding query).  You pass a function to the Google API, so in turn *your* API is written so that when you call it from elsewhere, you pass in a handler function.

Comment: Hi Pointy, my javascript isnt very good, so I can' understand you. Can you write an example callback function code in the code you posted? I tried googling for it but doesnt seem to be the callback function that I understand you are telling me about.

Comment: Well OK, but of course I have no idea what you want to do with the lat/lng information ...