# Geocoder method does not return values

Tags: jquery, api, google-maps

Geocoder method does not return values when calling it from a button click. I need the results to be stored in global variables "source_lat" and "source_long". Seems like my button click ends before geocoder could return values.

```
 function GeocoderStart(str) {
           geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
               geocoder_request = { 'address': str };
               geocoder.geocode(geocoder_request, function (results, status) {
                   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                       var country = extractFromAdress(results[0].address_components, "country");
                       if ((country != "India") & (country != "")) {
                           //alert("Error", "The address you entered refers to <b>" + results[0].formatted_address + "</b>. Please select only addresses in India using the autocomplete lookup.");                        
                           alert("Please select a valid address");
                           return false;
                       } else {
                           source_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                           source_long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                       }
                   } else {
                       alert("Error", "Unable to lookup address for the following reason: " + status);
                       return false;
                   }                  
               });
```

}

//Extract from address function

```
 function extractFromAdress(components, type) {  // taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313876/more-efficient-way-to-extract-address-components
            for (var i = 0; i < components.length; i++)
                for (var j = 0; j < components[i].types.length; j++)
                    if (components[i].types[j] == type) return components[i].long_name;
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: What DO you get? An alert of _Please select a valid address_ or the other one?

Comment: @putvande No alerts. and i dont get any values.

Comment: But you cannot return value form async method. You have to code logic once you get value, inside request callback method. Here using any global variable seems just wrong

Comment: Any errors at all? And how do you know you are not getting the values you want?

Comment: @putvande Am trying to use the values to display it in a label on my button click. So i dont get any values there.

Comment: Are the function extractFromAdress being called?

Comment: @A.Wolff I dont return anything from this code. Am just trying to assign it to a global variable.

Comment: But as other mentioned before, the Geocoder is asynchronous so when you click the button, you won't get the result immediately. You need to wait for the Geocoder to finish.

Comment: Hehe.. sorry, auto-correct.

Comment: But then, how do you use this global variables, obviously before the request is completed

Comment: @eNepper Please find the edited code

Comment: Could you try to insert an alert after the global variables are set alerting the content of the global variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function returning undefined in Geocoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967397/function-returning-undefined-in-geocoder)

Answer (score 0):

heres how I achieve geocode on a recent project - maybe it'll help shed light on the issue you're facing:

```
$.getJSON("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Pensyvania%20Ave%20Washington%20DC&sensor=false",
dataType = 'json',
function (data) {

    if (data['results']) {

         var country = data['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name'];
         if ((country != "India") & (country != "")) {

            console.log("sorry, wrong country:)");

        } else {

            console.log("lat: " + data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'] + ",  lng: " + data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']);

        }
    }

});
```